# You have both xxx and xxx error: Error building trees git

Tags: git

Very confused by this error from git today:

```
You have both sdapp/app/www and sdapp/app/www/config.xml
error: Error building trees

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (109 ms @ 16/10/2013 23:38:35)
```

Now, while I am not 100% sure and can't find out how to test this, but I believe that config.xml may have been committed and deleted at some point. Not helpful I know, but this is the only thing that I can think of that might cause this error...

**Question**

How can I add this file without getting this error?

Comment: What is the command you are running?

Comment: Must be honest I'm using git tourtose. But I'm trying to hunt it down for you guys. Otherwise, its just a standard add then commit of the file.

Comment: I original thought it was only the config.xml, but now its actually any file/folder within the app/www folder. If that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is you have a symbolic link in the `sdapp/app/` directory called `www` while also having a `www` directory which I believe is possible.

Try :

```
cd sdapp/app/
rm www
```

Comment: Genuis. I did used to have a smylink set up :) Let me check

Comment: Fan bloody tastic :) Thanks very much, I'd completely forgotten about the committed smylink, even if I had remember, i wouldn't have known :)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to move everything to a new local branch and then rebase against this branch. Step-by-step I did like this:

```
git checkout -b temp
git commit -am "Commit description"
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout temp
git rebase master
git checkout master
git rebase temp
git push
git branch -d temp # To remove temporary branch
```

This solved it for me.